# Rshiny: How to create features based on value selected from UI

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I am new with rshiny
How to create features based on value selected.
In data have delivery date, as per date selection from UI ("dateinput") calculate delay days and for every observation add new feature with value as "On time", "Late" or "Future".

I am new with rshiny & flexdashboard.

```
---
title: "Demo"
social: menu
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    navbar:
      - {title: "<i class='fa fa-info'></i> Report Based on date 05-01-2019", align: right}
---

# Add Date Picker for Generate report Based on It.
dateInput("RDate",
  label = "Report Date",
  value = "2019-05-01",
  min = NULL,
  max = NULL,
  format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
  startview = "month",
  language = "en",
  width = NULL
  )



Raw_data_1 <-mutate(Raw_data_1, OT_Due_date = ifelse(Raw_data_1$DueDate >=  input$RDate,"Future",
                              (ifelse(is.na(Raw_data_1$LastRcvd),
                                      (ifelse((Raw_data_1$Received >=Raw_data_1$Ordered),"On Time","Late")),
                                                ifelse((Raw_data_1$Received >=Raw_data_1$Ordered) &
                                                (Raw_data_1$LastRcvd <= Raw_data_1$DueDate),"On Time","Late")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced with flexdashboard but as you are using shiny as runtime you have to work your data a bit differently.
1) All data that gets modified by an input$ value must be in an Reactive expression
2) renders must be specifically called by renderTable/renderPlot, etc

This is the code that ended up working for me:

````
---
title: "Demo"
social: menu
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
    navbar:
      - {title: "<i class='fa fa-info'></i> Report Based on date 05-01-2019", align: right}
---

```{r global, include = FALSE}
### ADD HERE YOUR RAW DATA AND LIBRARIES
```

# Add Date Picker for Generate report Based on It.

```{r}
dateInput("RDate",
  label = "Report Date",
  value = "2019-05-01",
  min = NULL,
  max = NULL,
  format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
  startview = "month",
  language = "en",
  width = NULL
  )
```

```{r}
Raw_data <- reactive({
  Raw_data_1 <- mutate(Raw_data_1, 
    OT_Due_date = ifelse(Raw_data_1$DueDate >= input$RDate,
                    "Future", 
                    ifelse(is.na(Raw_data_1$LastRcvd), 
                      ifelse((Raw_data_1$Received >= Raw_data_1$Ordered),
                        "On Time",
                        "Late"
                      ), 
                      ifelse(Raw_data_1$Received >= Raw_data_1$Ordered & 
                      Raw_data_1$LastRcvd <= Raw_data_1$DueDate,
                        "On Time",
                        "Late"
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
})

renderTable(Raw_data())
```{r}
````